# The inline constraint resolver of type 'DefaultInlineConstraintResolver' was unable to resolve the following inline constraint:

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

I wanted to use attribute routing. My code is:

```
[Route("api/ws/{parm: myClass}")]
public void Post(myClass parm)
{ ... }
```

This resulted in an exception in `WebApiConfig.Register` as follows:

> The inline constraint resolver of type 'DefaultInlineConstraintResolver' was unable to resolve the following inline constraint: ' myClass'.

What could be the cause of this error?

`myClass` is a complex object, ie not a simple value type but a class with multiple properties.  Are such parameters allowed?

Comment: Since you cannot pass a complex object through a URL (which is the only responsibility that routing has), it is unclear what you hope to achieve from this. Complex objects *can* be posted via HTTP POST and *can* end up as parameters of action methods, but the URL has nothing to do with that (other than selecting the correct action method to post to, of course).

Comment: Show an example of what `myClass` would look like and how you would want to use the properties as they relate to the route parameter. Depending on the complexity of the class you can create a [Custom Route Constraint](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#constraints)

Comment: The data is passed in the Post body. I was mistaken in thinking that the parameters overloading could be used to match different data types being received. I didn't fully understand whether routes would also apply to data in the post body.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't use objects in routing attributes; [this article](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) has a table with a full list of allowed attribute types.